# Select the first x letters of each row

Tags: emacs

I have the following org doc

[image]

How could  only select vertically  the numer) part of each row

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can look at [rectangle](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) operations in emacs

Comment: @marcin: No, there's nothing wrong with posting Emacs questions to Stackoverflow. It depends on what the question is and what readers the OP wants to consider the question.

Comment: @AlainMerigot: You might consider developing that into an answer by summarizing some of the info at that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has a mean to manipulate arbitrary rectangles in the same way regions are manipulate.
You need first to select a rectangular region:

- select a starting point with <kbd>C-<Space></kbd>
- go to the opposite point of the rectangular region

Then you can apply several 'rectangle' actions.
All these actions all prefixed with <kbd>C-x r</kbd>
Most useful are :

- <kbd>C-x r M-w</kbd> copies a rectangular region and it is probably what you need
- <kbd>C-x r k</kbd> Cut (kill)) a rectangular region
- <kbd>C-x r y</kbd> will yank a copied rectangle at a given position.

Rectangle actions are available in every mode, but to facilitate rectangle manipulation, you can use <kbd>C-x <Space></kbd>; It is a toggle that turns standard copy/cut/paste actions (<kbd>M-w</kbd>, <kbd>C-w</kbd>, <kbd>C-y</kbd> and so on), to apply on rectangles. You also have a visual feedback on the selected rectangle.

Rectangle mode is very handy to manipulate columns in a tabular display (for instance to permute two columns).

<kbd>C-x r N</kbd> (rectangle number lines) is also useful to insert an automatic numbering of lines and it may also solve your problem.

Comment: ty,  also found the multiple cursors plugin.

Comment: For me, the most useful rectangle operation by far is `C-x r t` (`string-rectangle`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [evil](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil), you can type <kbd>C-v</kbd> to enter `visual mode` and use <kbd>j</kbd> to select the row you want from top to down.